# Sublime text 2 error: When building game

Tags: python, pygame, sublimetext2, building, tic-tac-toe

I keep getting this error

```
Welcome to Tic Tac Toe
Do you want to be X or O?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\last try.py", line 145, in <module>
    playerLetter, computerLetter = inputPlayerLetter()
  File "C:\Python27\last try.py", line 27, in inputPlayerLetter
    letter = input().upper()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1
```

When I put in the code to a python tic tac toe game. Can some one please help?!

The code for the tic tac toe game is from http://inventwithpython.com/tictactoe.py

*note*: I tried installing and configuring sublimerepl and it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: forgive me for the formatting im a noob. the blockquote part is the message im getting. minus all the enter code here messages.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the code in a terminal, because the `input()` function is asking you to enter some text.

The Sublime environment is not sufficient.